# What is the registry key to find if Windows Error Reporting is enabled?

Tags: windows, logging

I would like to know if Windows Error Reporting is enabled on the OS on which my code runs.
What is the registry key to find this information?

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows 7 (and probably Vista, perhaps XP) Windows Error Reporting is the Wersvc service.

You can check it's start state settings in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WerSvc\`

If `Start` (REG_DWORD) is set to `4`, it's disabled at startup.

If you want to find out if it's actually running or not, then you'll need to look someplace other than the registry.

Comment: thanks a lot :) if i would like to find out whether WER is running or not, where can i look ?

Comment: It's now a matter of where to look to see if it's running, it's HOW to look, and there's many ways to do it.  If you are a coder, then you should be able to use functions provided in your language of choice.  From a command prompt you can use 'sc query wersvc'.

Answer (score 0):

For Vista the keys are 
•HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
•HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting

I believe in XP it is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\PCHealth\ErrorReporting